# Can I still get the Scorched Map reward if I didn't get it on my first visit to the Nafusaan Mountains?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

Infinity Blade 3’s Dragoor Quest starts with an Interlude in the Nafusaan Mountains.

If you already have the Scorched Map at that point, there's a building you can click on and get rewarded with a rare gem.

However, I didn't have that map, and didn't realize that once I'd gone to the Nafusaan Mountains, Dragoor would fly off into the world and the Nafusaan Mountains would no longer be available.  I read up on the quest and read that when Dragoor was almost defeated, she'd fly back to the Nafusaan Mountains.

Well, she did, but when I enter the Nafusaan Mountains now, I'm immediately face to face with Dragoor and that building's nowhere to be seen.  Is there any way to get that gem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Kingdom Come Dragoor Guide on AppUnwrapper](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2014/09/04/infinity-blade-iii-3-kingdom-come-dragoor-guide/), the answer is "Yes"; if you slay Dragoor at the Nafusaan Mountains, you get to see that building again and can get the map loot, in addition to the loot Dragoor drops and in the chests it guarded.  It looks like the location becomes open after you beat Dragoor and you can go back as you please to grab the loot.

What you **don't** want to do, according to that guide, is finish Act V before you've beaten Dragoor and collected that loot; then it might disappear entirely.

*EDITED TO ADD:*  I can now confirm that if you beat Dragoor, you can go back to that location and get the Scorched Map loot from the ruined building.  I didn't go onto to do Act V, so I don't know if the location will stay open after that.